# How does this code work to create buttons?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am wondering how exactly the following piece of code works (yes, it indeed works as intended, and it gives different values of tag, depending on which button was clicked.)
The point is: Aren't we reusing `button` 7 times, where are the other 6 buttons left? After executing this code do we really have memory reserved for 7 `UIButton`s?

Or as a more general question: Is this good programming style? The point is that I need to have a different action depending on which button was clicked, and this approach (with my limited objc skills) looked like the most straightforward.
Thanks in advance,
A beginning iOS developer.

```
UIButton *button;
for(int k=0;k<7;k++)
        {
             button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [button addTarget:self 
                       action:@selector(aMethod:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(80, 20+30*k, 30, 30);
            button.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            button.tag=k;
            [subview addSubview:button];
        }
```

Where the function aMethod: is defined as:

```
-(IBAction)aMethod:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *clickedButton=(UIButton *) sender;
   NSLog(@"Tag is: %d",clickedButton.tag);
}
```

Comment: Button in this case is just the point to an object, not an object itself.  every call of "[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];" within the for loop creates another instantiation of the object, but then set only the pointer (or reference) to that object into your button variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not reusing the `UIButton` seven times: each iteration of the loop creates a new instance of `UIButton` in a call to the class method `buttonWithType:`, and assigns it to the variable of the same name:

```
[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Your code would be better off if you declared that variable inside the loop:

```
for(int k=0;k<7;k++)
    {
         UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
         // ...the rest of the loop
    }
```

This is a very good programming style for situations when your buttons perform very similar actions. For example, calculator buttons differ only in the number that they insert. When the buttons perform actions that differ a lot (e.g. insertion vs. deletion) you are better off creating them separately, not in a loop, and servicing their clicks using separate methods.

Comment: Ok thanks, I must say: A whole new world opened up when I discovered I could create and use `UIButton`s (and other objects) programmatically, without using IB, without connecting the lines. Imho, this way of defining objects is much cleaner and intuitive.

Comment: +1 - You're not really servicing the action in the loop but creating the button's action point in the loop.

Comment: @trumpetlicks Thanks, I can see how the way I phrased it originally could have been misleading.

Comment: @ClausW There is an ongoing debate on "what is better" - using IB or coding your interface manually. Unfortunately, that's one of these questions that cannot be answered until everyone agrees on the meaning of "better" :)

Answer (score 0):

In this code you just create 7 buttons with different positions and tags. It is much more better, then duplicate creation code for 7 times. The one thing, that I can offer you - to create some enum for button tags to prevent code like this:

```
switch([button tag])
{
    case 1:
        // do something
        break;
    case 2:
        // do something else
        break;
    case 3:
        // exit
        break;
    .....
    default:
        assert(NO && @"unhandled button tag");
}
```

the code with enum values much more easy to read

```
switch([button tag])
{
    case kButtonForDoSomething:
        // do something
        break;
    case kButtonForDoSomethingElse:
        // do something else
        break;
    case kButtonExit:
        // exit
        break;
    .....
    default:
        assert(NO && @"unhandled button tag");
}
```

Comment: This code isn't too efficient, as you may not have a hardcoded amount of Buttons to create and needed them to work dynamically. With a `switch` case, you have to know how many buttons exists to build a case for each one.

Answer (score 0):

This code does suffice, you're creating 7 different buttons and adding them as subviews. Once you `-addSubview:`, the object is added to an array, Accessed via the `.subviews` property of `UIView`.

Although you should add UIButton *button in your for loop. So your code should look like below..

```
for(int k=0;k<7;k++)
    {
         UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   ....
}
```

If you needed to do something `out` of the for loop with the button then declaring it outside the loop makes sense, but this is not your case. Hope this helps.